# Easily open include filenames in vim?

Tags: vim, text-editor

Basically, I'm editing files that have include file names and I want a quick way of opening the file without having to type the path/filename:

```
include('inc/doctype.inc.php');
```

Is there an easy way to do this? (Ideally, I'd like to use :tabnew to open the file in a new tab.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> shortcut. Move your cursor on a path string, the exact cursor position is not important and then press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> in normal mode. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> stands for "**g**oto **f**ile".
See vims help page with `:h gf`:

> Uses the '**isfname**' option to find out which characters
>     are supposed to be in a file name.  Trailing
>     punctuation characters ".,:;!" are ignored.
>     Uses the '**path**' option as a list of directory names
>     to look for the file.  Also looks for the file
>     relative to the current file.
>     Uses the '**suffixesadd**' option to check for file names
>     with a suffix added.
>     If the file can't be found, '**includeexpr**' is used to
>     modify the name and another attempt is done.

To get back, use <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> in normal mode.
*Note:* This command brings the cursor position to older positions in the jump list. The opposite command is <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd> which brings the cursor to newer positions in the jump list.

Comment: Thanks! This works great, except for when I open one file and then open another file . . I can't get back to the original.  Still would be nice to be able to open into a new tab, but this is an improvement over the way I was working.

Comment: Great :) As glenn jackman said, to open the file in new window the gf shortcut should be proceeded by ctrl-w.

Comment: actually, ctrl+w gf opens the file in a new tab, exactly as CMB requested.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking about tab when writing window. Thanks for correction.

Comment: Is there a way to do this just by putting the cursor on the same line? Where it says "input"... Or perhaps less keystrokes by 2019?

Answer (score 5):

Put the cursor on the filename, then <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

`:h ctrl-w_gf`